# C# mimic associative array of unknown key-number (like in PHP)

Tags: c#, php, arrays, associative-array

Is there a possibility to create sth. like an associative array like in PHP?
I don't plan to create a game with some player-data, but I could easily explain this way what I want:

```
player["Name"] = "PName";
player["Custom"]["Gender"] = "Female";
player["Custom"]["Style"] = "S1";
player["Custom"]["Face"]["Main"] = "FM1";
player["Custom"]["Face"]["Eyes"] = "FE1";
player["Custom"]["Height"] = "180";
```

Also the **length** has to be **dynamic**, I don't **how many keys** there will be:

```
player["key1"]["key2"]=value
player["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"]...=value
```

What I need is sth. I could address like:

```
string name = player["Name"];
string gender = player["Custom"]["Gender"];
string style = player["Custom"]["Style"];
string faceMain = player["Custom"]["Face"]["Main"];
string faceEyes = player["Custom"]["Face"]["Eyes"];
string height = player["Custom"]["Height"];
```

Or in some way similar to this.

What I tried till now:

```
Dictionary<string, Hashtable> player = new Dictionary<string, Hashtable>();
player["custom"] = new Hashtable();
player["custom"]["Gender"] = "Female";
player["custom"]["Style"] = "S1";
```

But the problem starts here (only works with 2 keys):

```
player["custom"]["Face"] = new Hashtable();
player["Custom"]["Face"]["Main"] = "FM1";
```

Comment: [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) should have what you need. if not: the .net-generic-collections have a class for every purpose. the cleaner way, however, would be to define classes representing your player and its properties

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: To do with PHP: "associative array" exists in PHP but not in C#, I need a solution how to create sth. equivalent.

Comment: Could you explain how to do it with "dictionary" please? I tried "Dictionary<string, Hashtable> player = new Dictionary<string, Hashtable>();"
But it does only work on fixed key length.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with php, just because it exists in another language doesn't make the question relevant to the php.

Comment: Even with a dictionary you will only be able to work with 1 level of nesting while you want to be able to have a X number of nesting like you can in PHP. Since PHP is not a strongly typed language, this is possible in PHP, whether you like it or not. In c# however, every expression must have a type. This means that `foo["bar"]` can not sometimes be another array, and sometimes a value of your choosing, because there is no type (besides  `object`) that can be inferred to both. You could go with dynamic types, but that's just nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is strongly typed so it seems not easy to replicate this exact behavior.

A "possibility" :

```
public class UglyThing<K,E>
{
    private Dictionary<K, UglyThing<K, E>> dicdic = new Dictionary<K, UglyThing<K, E>>();

    public UglyThing<K, E> this[K key] 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (!this.dicdic.ContainsKey(key)) { this.dicdic[key] = new UglyThing<K, E>(); }
            return this.dicdic[key];
        } 
        set
        {
            this.dicdic[key] = value;
        } 
    }

    public E Value { get; set; }
}
```

Usage :

```
        var x = new UglyThing<string, int>();

        x["a"].Value = 1;
        x["b"].Value = 11;
        x["a"]["b"].Value = 2;
        x["a"]["b"]["c1"].Value = 3;
        x["a"]["b"]["c2"].Value = 4;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x["a"].Value);            // 1
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x["b"].Value);            // 11
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x["a"]["b"].Value);       // 2
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x["a"]["b"]["c1"].Value); // 3
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x["a"]["b"]["c2"].Value); // 4
```